# Delphi, Android - internet connections hangs

Tags: android, delphi

I have a strange problem with my FireMonkey app for Android. I am communicating with my server written in PHP by HTTPS protocol. This work with few of my clients. But one of them have problem - after a few successful operations, it looks like the connection hangs. After restarting program it’s normal again – for few minutes.

Exactly the same application in other of my clients works fine. The customer even gave me their phones with their SIM cards and in my home... everything works fine. When we change the SIM card to another GSM operator, it is a bit better, but the genre is the same. So it seems to me that this might be a problem with GSM coverage. But I do not understand what's going on. Have you ever had a similar problem?

The effect is identical for both idHTTP and TNetHTTPClient.

Every time I connect, I create a TNetHTTPClient component, and in the try-finally block I releases it.

Comment: Which version of Android?

Comment: This is Android 6.0